# Retaining data while modifying column data type

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to modify a data type while retaining the existing data. Here is the current setup:

```
create or replace type xyz.Varray2 is varray(50) of varchar2(20);

CREATE TABLE xyz.owner (
MODIFIED DATE,
ID Varchar(18),
STATE Varchar(2),
CONTRIBUTOR_IDS xyz.Varray2
)
```

An example record looks like this:

```
10-MAR-13 408923100000000002 CA VARRAY2('Bob', 'Tom', 'Mary', 'Henry', 'Bart')
```

I need to modify the `Varray2` data type to be a `varray(150)`. I would rather keep the `Varray2` type, but if necessary a new `Varray3` type could be created for use.

This table contains millions of records that need to be retained. In order to modify the existing `Varray2` type, I have to drop the table, which is my first problem. I tried to export the table and then import it after changing `Varray2` to 150, but it gives an error that the types are different. I tried to create a backup table with the new data type, but it gave an error when trying to save the data (incompatible type again). It would not let me modify the column data type on the fly, either (`ORA-22859`).

I am on the verge of writing a cursor or even a bash script to parse spooled output to generate `INSERT` commands to insert into the new table, but that seems excessive. I was hoping someone here would be able to come up with a simpler solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The upper limit of the `varray2` data type can be increased with `alter type` statement:

```
create or replace type Varray2 is varray(50) of varchar2(20);
/
TYPE VARRAY2 compiled


create table owner (
  modified        date,          
  id1             Varchar2(18),  --   use varchar2 data type, not varchar. 
  state           Varchar2(2),  
  contributer_ids Varray2
)
/

table OWNER created.
```

Current information about `varray2` data type:

```
SQL> clear screen;
SQL> column type_name format a11;
SQL> column upper_bound format a11

SQL> select t.type_name
  2       , t.upper_bound
  3   from all_coll_types t
  4  where type_name = 'VARRAY2';

TYPE_NAME   UPPER_BOUND
----------- -----------
VARRAY2              50
```

Change the upper limit of the `varray2` data type:

```
SQL> alter type Varray2 modify limit 150 cascade;

type VARRAY2 altered.
```

After the upper limit of the `varray2` data type has changed:

```
SQL> clear screen;
SQL> column type_name format a11;
SQL> column upper_bound format a11

SQL> select t.type_name
  2       , t.upper_bound
  3   from all_coll_types t
  4  where type_name = 'VARRAY2';

TYPE_NAME   UPPER_BOUND
----------- -----------
VARRAY2             150
```

`cascade` clause of the `alter type` statement propagates the data type change to the dependent objects, whether it's a table or another data type.